# Run Multiple Mysql updates through a php submit box

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file with hundreds of mysql commands that need to be run on my database on a daily basis I would like somebody who doesn't have access to phpmyadmin to run it. I have created a php form that the user can copy and paste the code into but it only works if you enter one command at a time. Help!
this is the code

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$username= "root";
$db_name="db573937554"; // Database name
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sqlcode = $_POST['sqlcode'];
$sql=$sqlcode;
echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){Header("Location: index.php");}else {echo 'Error - Ask Mike for  help it will make his day';}?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is kind of a disaster waiting to happen. Are these trusted people I hope?

Comment: Is this for DB maintenence/cleanup?  Just put it on a cron job and eliminate user error/access.

Comment: Also, I hope they are competent people in SQL. The wrong command and you may not like the results!

Comment: it's a bit of a mistake from start to finish. i only know php and needed to build a system for engineers to log data offline.so using xampp the database logs all the sql commands the engineers make offline in a text file they then press a button when online and it sends the data in an email to the office. From here it is copied and pasted into the text box then the code above updates the offices logs... hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll never recomend you to have an open interface to make queries to the database, but if you want, the best aproach is to define a delimiter that is never pressent in the queries (; or ##### For example).
Ask your people to finish each query with it, and change the code that way:

```
<?php 
$delimiter = ";";
$host="localhost";
$username= "root";
$db_name="db573937554"; // Database name
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sqlcode = $_POST['sqlcode'];
$sqls=explode($delimiter,$sqlcode);
foreach($sqls as $sql){
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error - Ask Mike for help it will make his day:'.$sql);
}
Header("Location: index.php");?>
```

Comment: It runs the code perfectly but come up with the error message still. I removed the.    or die('error - ...) and seems to do the trick. Thanks.